# OAuth for request from Msteams to azure bot messaging endpoint

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

Currently, we're using bot framework v4 to connect Msteams and the bot.
The question is that we need to configure the API gateway to expose the messaging endpoint which can receive messages from Msteams.
And our API gateway is required to use our own Authentication server.
AFAICS, the current Authentication flow use the bot connector service to do the authentication.
I'm wondering if there's a way that we can use our own authentication?

I know we can configure OAuth connection settings, but that's for request for the third party online service. And this is documented as user Authentication type [User authentication](https://urldefense.proofpoint.com/v2/url?u=https-3A__learn.microsoft.com_en-2Dus_azure_bot-2Dservice_bot-2Dbuilder-2Dconcept-2Dauthentication-2Dtypes-3Fview-3Dazure-2Dbot-2Dservice-2D4.0-23user-2Dauthentication&d=DwMGaQ&c=jf_iaSHvJObTbx-siA1ZOg&r=i02OAK2ZdbPYdC7yGKfXnMFFbxp8YXXYIKGyo2kE_3E&m=ag_M5OLMgUM_j8TH-EzLSnazl7DaE27H01ivT1E-MsYVs_aU4_a81G83h6BZYSWP&s=4GADPcI6jiCNZ3d2FnMj53gD_L3iwEHDgIv_ClWcCcc&e=%22https://urldefense.proofpoint.com/v2/url?u=https-3A__learn.microsoft.com_en-2Dus_azure_bot-2Dservice_bot-2Dbuilder-2Dconcept-2Dauthentication-2Dtypes-3Fview-3Dazure-2Dbot-2Dservice-2D4.0-23user-2Dauthentication&d=DwMGaQ&c=jf_iaSHvJObTbx-siA1ZOg&r=i02OAK2ZdbPYdC7yGKfXnMFFbxp8YXXYIKGyo2kE_3E&m=ag_M5OLMgUM_j8TH-EzLSnazl7DaE27H01ivT1E-MsYVs_aU4_a81G83h6BZYSWP&s=4GADPcI6jiCNZ3d2FnMj53gD_L3iwEHDgIv_ClWcCcc&e=%22).
Here, I mean can the bot authentication can be customized with my own OAuth server, especially for the  [Authenticate requests from the Bot Connector service to your bot](https://urldefense.proofpoint.com/v2/url?u=https-3A__learn.microsoft.com_en-2Dus_azure_bot-2Dservice_rest-2Dapi_bot-2Dframework-2Drest-2Dconnector-2Dauthentication-3Fview-3Dazure-2Dbot-2Dservice-2D4.0-26tabs-3Dmultitenant-23connector-2Dto-2Dbot&d=DwMGaQ&c=jf_iaSHvJObTbx-siA1ZOg&r=i02OAK2ZdbPYdC7yGKfXnMFFbxp8YXXYIKGyo2kE_3E&m=ag_M5OLMgUM_j8TH-EzLSnazl7DaE27H01ivT1E-MsYVs_aU4_a81G83h6BZYSWP&s=qSJ2Rdg3hzcCNouAu4TiFUdcrLFjm_jW6uBYpwIRIdw&e=%22https://urldefense.proofpoint.com/v2/url?u=https-3A__learn.microsoft.com_en-2Dus_azure_bot-2Dservice_rest-2Dapi_bot-2Dframework-2Drest-2Dconnector-2Dauthentication-3Fview-3Dazure-2Dbot-2Dservice-2D4.0-26tabs-3Dmultitenant-23connector-2Dto-2Dbot&d=DwMGaQ&c=jf_iaSHvJObTbx-siA1ZOg&r=i02OAK2ZdbPYdC7yGKfXnMFFbxp8YXXYIKGyo2kE_3E&m=ag_M5OLMgUM_j8TH-EzLSnazl7DaE27H01ivT1E-MsYVs_aU4_a81G83h6BZYSWP&s=qSJ2Rdg3hzcCNouAu4TiFUdcrLFjm_jW6uBYpwIRIdw&e=%22)

I've tried [Authenticate requests from the Bot Connector service to your bot](https://urldefense.proofpoint.com/v2/url?u=https-3A__learn.microsoft.com_en-2Dus_azure_bot-2Dservice_rest-2Dapi_bot-2Dframework-2Drest-2Dconnector-2Dauthentication-3Fview-3Dazure-2Dbot-2Dservice-2D4.0-26tabs-3Dmultitenant-23connector-2Dto-2Dbot&d=DwMGaQ&c=jf_iaSHvJObTbx-siA1ZOg&r=i02OAK2ZdbPYdC7yGKfXnMFFbxp8YXXYIKGyo2kE_3E&m=ag_M5OLMgUM_j8TH-EzLSnazl7DaE27H01ivT1E-MsYVs_aU4_a81G83h6BZYSWP&s=qSJ2Rdg3hzcCNouAu4TiFUdcrLFjm_jW6uBYpwIRIdw&e=%22https://urldefense.proofpoint.com/v2/url?u=https-3A__learn.microsoft.com_en-2Dus_azure_bot-2Dservice_rest-2Dapi_bot-2Dframework-2Drest-2Dconnector-2Dauthentication-3Fview-3Dazure-2Dbot-2Dservice-2D4.0-26tabs-3Dmultitenant-23connector-2Dto-2Dbot&d=DwMGaQ&c=jf_iaSHvJObTbx-siA1ZOg&r=i02OAK2ZdbPYdC7yGKfXnMFFbxp8YXXYIKGyo2kE_3E&m=ag_M5OLMgUM_j8TH-EzLSnazl7DaE27H01ivT1E-MsYVs_aU4_a81G83h6BZYSWP&s=qSJ2Rdg3hzcCNouAu4TiFUdcrLFjm_jW6uBYpwIRIdw&e=%22)
but the OAuth is provided by the Bot Connector service, can we define our own OAuth server?

Comment: Could you please refer this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-identity-providers?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=adv2%2Cga2#other-identity-providers

Answer (score 0):

Azure supports several identity providers. You can get a complete list, along with the related details, by running the following Azure console commands:

```
az login
az bot authsetting list-providers
```

Reference doc link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-identity-providers?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=adv2%2Cga2#other-identity-providers

Comment: Thanks Chetan, I mean this is for external service, and you can specify the identity providers. And I'd like to specify the OAuth server of the request from the bot connector service to the bot.